# From notification to Fragment with Rxjava?

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification, rx-java

I am building an app with push notifications. I want to , when user clicks on notification to send him to the Fragment1. But I want to do that with Rxjava. How to do that?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("onCreate", "ONCREATE");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");

    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen u onCreate!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("Create", "Kraj onCreatea");
        }
    }

    dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    dugme2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (view == dugme) {
                fragment = new Fragment1();
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });


    dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");
            Log.d("Log", "Uspesno ste se pretplatili");
        }
    });

}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Resume");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("action");
    Log.d("msg", "msg");
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.equals("goToFragment1")) {
            Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, fragment1);
            Log.d("FragmentTransaction", "Fragment je promenjen!");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            Log.d("onResume", "Kraj resuma");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is myFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "From " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Body " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("Msg", "Poruka je stigla");
}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    Intent intent=new Intent(myFirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Naslov")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());



}
```

And, I want to send user from notification to fragment1 for all situations(when app is in the foreground, when app is in the background and when app is killed)

Comment: Start reading about RxJava, you can not expect people refactor your code. Here you can see some most common use examples about RXJava https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to use RxJava in your situation. About open your Fragment even when your app is in background it's is quite easy.

Take a look at my production code which does the same:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.ACTION_OPEN_ALBUM);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("id", albumId);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.parseInt(albumId), intent, 0);

pendingIntent.send();
```

The main difference between mine and yours is the flags. You are using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** which expect that there's one MainActivity instance running in your task.

Look the documentation below:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
>
> If set, and the activity being launched is
>   already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it
>   will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top)
>   old activity as a new Intent.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

When your app is not running you don't have a task yet, so you should use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK instead.

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>
> If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this
>   history stack.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Your code should look like this:

```
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("your.package.WHATEVER_ACTION");
    intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(logo)
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentTitle("Naslov")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());
}
```

In your manifest you should set the action as intent filter:

```
    <activity
        android:name="your.package.YourActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your.package.WHATEVER_ACTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Hope that it helps!

Best regards.

Comment: Okay, but I am litlle confused now.. this FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is when app is not running.or if app is in the background?

Comment: You should use just FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. It will open you activity in a whole new task on history stack

Comment: I put this yours flag and again it sends me to the first page on Main activity, not to the fragment1

Comment: you should keep your '''intent.putExtra("action", "goToFragment1");'''

Comment: are you using instant run on android studio?

Comment: Please Yes, I use instant run...Please read again carefully my whole code, this is very important to me.

Comment: Ok, could you clean and rebuild your project? It could be a bug on instant run.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm creating intent based on ACTION now. Could you try this?